# Three Tables INNER JOIN and WHERE Clause

Tags: mysql, sql, database, t-sql

I have four tables
1. tbl_threads
2. tbl_comments
3. tbl_votes
4. tbl_users

suppose the currently logged in user_id =3
thread_id = 10

Now I have to retrieve the following data

```
All the fields from tbl_comments where tbl_comments.thread_id =10
All the fields from tbl_users based on the common key tbl_users.user_id = tbl_comments.user_id
All the fields from tbl_votes Where user_id =3 And tbl_votes.comment_id =tbl_comments.comment_id
```

How can I perform all this function with one single query?

I have tried the following query but it gives me the wrong results

```
SELECT tbl_comments.*
     , tbl_users.*
     , tbl_votes.* 
FROM tbl_comments 
INNER JOIN tbl_users 
on tbl_comments.user_id = tbl_users.user_id 
WHERE thread_id= 10
INNER JOIN tbl_votes 
on tbl_votes.comment_id = tbl_comments.comment_id 
WHERE tbl_votes.user_id= 3
```

Comment: Please modify your question and show us what have you tried.  You have not mentioned about tbl_users

Comment: Does that query run? How does it return the wrong results? Your current query does not select where user_id = 3 and you have conflicting thread_id values.

Comment: @Byron, Sorry I have re-updated my query. You can Check Now. The Query Runs but it generates duplicate values and not the desired results. Actually, I do not know properly that How to use Two Where Clause with Three Inner Joins.

Comment: There should only be one where clause you can do something like `WHERE thread_id= 10 AND tbl_votes.user_id= 3` at the end instead.

Comment: You should really make separate queries. They are all different results with different cardinality. These things should be kept simple.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the column `thread_id` is in the `tbl_comments` table, change the first `where` to `and`:

```
SELECT tbl_comments.*
     , tbl_users.*
     , tbl_votes.* 
FROM tbl_comments 
INNER JOIN tbl_users 
on tbl_comments.user_id = tbl_users.user_id 
and  tbl_comments.thread_id= 10
INNER JOIN tbl_votes 
on tbl_votes.comment_id = tbl_comments.comment_id 
WHERE tbl_votes.user_id= 3
```

And although your question mentions a table named `tbl_threads`, you don't show any reference to it in your example.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT O.OrderNumber, CONVERT(date,O.OrderDate) AS Date, 
       P.ProductName, I.Quantity, I.UnitPrice 
  FROM [Order] O 
  JOIN OrderItem I ON O.Id = I.OrderId 
  JOIN Product P ON P.Id = I.ProductId
ORDER BY O.OrderNumber
```